# How to send hidden parameters in the request using selenium

Tags: security, http, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to send hidden parameters in the request using selenium.
The parameters are not visible to the end user but go as a part of http request. And my selenium script is not able to simulate the same. Due to which I am not able to fetch the results from the server. Any suggestion

```
TravelMultiController.ajaxSearchResult(302) | search:org.travel.model.Search@cf021a8[
      originlocation=Indira Gandhi Airport(DEL) near Delhi in India
      destinationlocation=Chhatrapati Shivaji International Airport(BOM) near Mumbai in India
      originlocationcode=DEL
      destinationlocationcode=BOM
      departuredatetime=2015-05-12
      returndatetime=2015-05-13
      cabin=Economy
      adt=1
      cnn=0
      inf=0
      prefered_airline=
      originlocationcity=Delhi
      destinationlocationcity=Mumbai
      destinationCountry=India
    ] memberId: 2800000101
    [SIB] 2015-03-20 13:43:08,269 INFO - TravelManagerImpl.airSearch(405) | called..org.travel.model.Search@cf021a8[
      originlocation=Indira Gandhi Airport(DEL) near Delhi in India
      destinationlocation=Chhatrapati Shivaji International Airport(BOM) near Mumbai in India
      originlocationcode=DEL //(not able to replicate)
      destinationlocationcode=BOM  //(not able to replicate)
      departuredatetime=2015-05-12
      returndatetime=2015-05-13
      cabin=Economy
      adt=1
      cnn=0
      inf=0
      prefered_airline=
      originlocationcity=Delhi
      destinationlocationcity=Mumbai
      destinationCountry=India
    ]
```

I am not able to send these two parameters originlocationcode=DEL
destinationlocationcode=BOM in my request. please suggest some work around to do this.

Comment: Can you show some code? How exactly are you sending parameters using Selenium?

Comment: hidden parameters?
Are you talking about some html tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not support by selenium.

You might be able to make it work by writing a javascript function that sends this request from your current browser session through the executeScript method on WebDriver.

Keep in mind that the purpose of Selenium is to simulate a real user, not send backend requests.  It is possible you would find a more suitable tool in JMeter, or by writing your own interface for sending requests such as this.

If authentication cookies are the issue for why you are trying to do this in Selenium -- WebDriver.manage().getCookies() will help you with that.  You can pull the cookies out and throw them into a request.